# LangChain with HuggingFace model and DuckDuckSearch not working

Tags: python, langchain

I'm trying to create an agent that uses HuggingFace models and also uses internet search to answer the queries

```
import os
import getpass

from langchain.agents import load_tools
from langchain.agents import initialize_agent
from langchain.llms import OpenAI
from langchain.agents import load_huggingface_tool
from langchain import PromptTemplate, HuggingFaceHub, LLMChain

os.environ\["HUGGINGFACEHUB_API_TOKEN"\] = getpass.getpass("HF Token:")

llm = HuggingFaceHub(
repo_id="huggingfaceh4/zephyr-7b-alpha",
model_kwargs={"temperature": 0.5, "max_length": 64, "max_new_tokens": 512},
)
tools = load_tools(\["ddg-search"\], llm=llm)


agent = initialize_agent(tools, llm, agent="zero-shot-react-description", verbose=True)

agent.run("What is LangChain and how does it work? ")
```

But I keep getting `Observation: the action to take, should be one of [duckduckgo_search] is not a valid tool, try one of [duckduckgo_search].` and it just keeps looping without any useful error. How can I fix this?

Thank you